# How to use Scalatest to develop a compiler-plugin in Scala

Tags: scala

Actually I'm developing a compiler plugin for Scala according to the article on http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140.

Here is the code of the plugin:

```
package localhost

import scala.tools.nsc
import nsc.Global
import nsc.Phase
import nsc.plugins.Plugin
import nsc.plugins.PluginComponent

class DivByZero(val global: Global) extends Plugin {
  import global._

  val name = "divbyzero"
  val description = "checks for division by zero"
  val components = List[PluginComponent](Component)

  private object Component extends PluginComponent {
    val global: DivByZero.this.global.type = DivByZero.this.global
    val runsAfter = "refchecks"
    // Using the Scala Compiler 2.8.x the runsAfter should be written as below
    // val runsAfter = List[String]("refchecks");
    val phaseName = DivByZero.this.name
    def newPhase(_prev: Phase) = new DivByZeroPhase(_prev)    

    class DivByZeroPhase(prev: Phase) extends StdPhase(prev) {
      override def name = DivByZero.this.name
      def apply(unit: CompilationUnit) {
        for ( tree @ Apply(Select(rcvr, nme.DIV), List(Literal(Constant(0)))) <- unit.body;
             if rcvr.tpe <:< definitions.IntClass.tpe) 
          {
            unit.error(tree.pos, "definitely division by zero")
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm doing the things mentioned there and wrote some makefile which compiles everything and then creates a jar-file. Then I'm loading the the plugin jar file with the testfile with the following command:

```
scalac -Xplugin:myplugin.jar test.scala
```

and see what the output is. I don't like this way because I knew from ruby how to do tdd and bdd. I installed Scalatest http://www.scalatest.org/. Is it in someway possible to test the jar-file or the class divbyzero? I know the plugin will first be load when executes with a file. I'm very wired in my head and don't know if it is possible to directly test the plugin class without creating the jar file (or is it even possible to test some functions and classes of the jar file)?

If no one can help me, I can keep on developing like in the good old days

Thanks for your time and help
Matthias

Comment: Since the scala compiler comes as jar, can you not add it to your IDE's classpath and call it from your test files?

Comment: I didn't this working with eclipse or netbeans. I have to tell them in every new compilation, where the jar-file is. That's the cause why I wrote a makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at mock objects (I like [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), but there are many others) and some refactoring.

When you refer to your makefile, I get the impression you're using good old make. If so, might I suggest you look at something like [SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/), [Gradle](http://gradle.org/), or, as you're coming from the Ruby world, [BuildR](http://buildr.apache.org/). All of them have built in support for various scala test frameworks.

Comment: I actually wrote a Rakefile, if you want I can post the content.

Comment: @Matthias Guenther: That would make this a rake question, which is cool. I would reiterate my suggestion to move to BuildR as it's derived from Rake and uses Ruby as its language so you should be conferable with it.

Comment: @sblundy you think, this would make it possible to add mock objects or what is the benefit of using BuildR?

Comment: @Matthias Guenther: It has built in support of ScalaTest. Adding mock objects would simply be a matter of adding the appropriate dependency. See http://buildr.apache.org/testing.html

Comment: I think we still don't understand each other :), let me explain my concerns again. With the help of a compiler plugin I traverse the abstract syntax tree (ast) of an example program and check the ast against certain rules. The rules are defined in my compiler plugin and will be executed, when I traverse the ast. But the rules/method in my compiler plugin will only be executed if I create the jar file of my compiler plugin and then load it with my example program.

Comment: In my eyes there is no possibility to explicitly test my rules with assertion except if I write assertions to my method definitions but this would mess up my production code with test code :). Hope now my problems get clearer

Comment: @Matthias Guenther: It sounds like you expect to do a full integration test, as opposed to unit tests. That's also possible, but will require a lot of work. As for unit tests, it's an art that's beyond the scope of this comment. I highly recommend it. Mock objects are very helpful for testing the internals of your classes. But good unit testing requires that you structure you code differently, usually for the better, dividing it up into testable chunks.

Comment: @sblundy I see and don't quite know how to do it in Scala :) because the development of a compiler plugin is very special. All examples about of other developed compiler plugin don't include any test-files so far. Maybe there is to much overhead to use this method.

Answer (score 19):

You can invoke the Scala compiler, plus plugins, programmatically with code like the following:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.{Settings, Global}
import scala.tools.nsc.io.VirtualDirectory
import scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter
import scala.tools.nsc.util.BatchSourceFile

// prepare the code you want to compile
val code = "object Foo extends Application { println(42 / 0) }"
val sources = List(new BatchSourceFile("<test>", code))

val settings = new Settings
// save class files to a virtual directory in memory
settings.outputDirs.setSingleOutput(new VirtualDirectory("(memory)", None))

val compiler = new Global(settings, new ConsoleReporter(settings)) {
  override protected def computeInternalPhases () {
    super.computeInternalPhases
    for (phase <- new DivByZero(this).components)
      phasesSet += phase
  }
}
new compiler.Run() compileSources(sources)
```

Note that this code requires that `scala-compiler.jar` and `scala-library.jar` be on the classpath when executing the code. If you are running your tests from within something like SBT, this will unfortunately not be the case.

To get things running from within SBT, you have to do some hoop jumping:

```
val settings = new Settings
val loader = getClass.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader]
val entries = loader.getURLs map(_.getPath)
// annoyingly, the Scala library is not in our classpath, so we have to add it manually
val sclpath = entries find(_.endsWith("scala-compiler.jar")) map(
  _.replaceAll("scala-compiler.jar", "scala-library.jar"))
settings.classpath.value = ClassPath.join((entries ++ sclpath) : _*)
```

If you are running from within some other build environment, you might find that `scala-library.jar` is already on the classpath, or if you're really lucky, then everything you need is on the standard Java classpath, in which case you can replace the above with:

```
val settings = new Settings
settings.usejavacp.value = true
```

You can print out the value of the Java classpath with `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` and you can of course print out `entries` from the above code to see the classpath used by the class loader that is loading your test code.

Comment: Great post - really helped me when writing a plugin to do dependency analysis. Note that should the output be to a real directory, rather than a virtual one, then I think you should use  

`settings.d.value="path-to-directory-as-string"`

instead of  

`settings.outputDirs.setSingleOutput...`

The former invokes the latter, but also makes the settings `outdir` method consistent.

Comment: With sbt 1.3.8 + Scala 2.13.3  the line `val loader = getClass.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader]` (while running in sbt shell) produces `java.lang.ClassCastException: sbt.internal.LayeredClassLoader cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add to samskivert's answer. Overriding `computeInternalPhases` forces to inject the phases of the plugin into the whole phaseSet, however, the compiler doesn't treat them as part of the plugin. So for instance, if you want to pass an option to your plugin `"-P:divbyzero:someoption"` using:

`settings.pluginOptions.appendToValue("divbyzero:someoption")`

you will get the following compilation error:

`error: bad option: -P:divbyzero:someoption`

and that is because compiler doesn't know anything about a plugin named `divbyzero`.

The more appropriate way of adding plugin would be to override `loadRoughPluginsList` method and add plugins there, rather than manually inject every phase of the plugin into compilation phaseSet:

```
override protected def loadRoughPluginsList: List[Plugin] =
  new DivByZero(this) :: super.loadRoughPluginsList
```