# How to call the scala interpreter in a Simple Build Tool project?

Tags: scala, interpreter, sbt

my scala program is using the compiler interface from scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain. When I am compiling with scalac, everything works as expected. But when I compile with sbt it still compiles, but on execution it throws the following error message in the call of the interpret-method from the IMain instance:

```
Failed to initialize compiler: object scala not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
```

If I use settings.usejavacp.value = true on the IMain instance, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Error: typeConstructor inapplicable for <none>
```

My SBT project definition:

```
class Project(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info){
    val scalaSwing = "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.9.0"
    val scalaCompiler = "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.9.0"
}
```

What's wrong here? And how can I use the interpreter in a Simple Build Tool Project?

I'm using **Scala 2.9.0** and **Simple Build Tool 0.7.7**

Comment: Do you *fork* when running? If not try that first. See http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Forking

Comment: Thank you, this almost did the trick. I added `override def fork = forkRun` to the project definition. The interpreter can run simple code, but cannot instantiate classes defined in the project. I could add a working directory for the fork. But which one should I take?

Comment: After experimenting with some paths it is working with: `override def fork = forkRun(new File("target/scala_2.9.0/classes"))` Isn't that a kind of bad workaround?

Comment: I encountered this too. The problem, as you discovered, is that the forked job doesn't know anything about the project classpaths. A more general problem is that an embedded Scala interpreter does not necessarily inherit the classpath of the parent Scala process. The workaround that I use is to create an SBT task that puts all the classpath elements (target/, lib_managed/, etc) in the *Java* classpath system property; then, when I launch an interpreter, I use the `usejavacp` option.

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713031/how-to-use-scalatest-to-develop-a-compiler-plugin-in-scala/4937135#4937135

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the SBT wiki: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Faq.html#How+do+I+use+the+Scala+interpreter+in+my+code%3F

There's an entry about getting the interpreter running.

Comment: Finally after migrating to sbt 0.10 it worked as stated in the FAQ. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

```
sbt console // Starts a Scala interpreter
```

Here is the new FAQ (the previous answer is obsolete)

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/faq.html

You can find also the FAQ for more recent versions.
Note that `sbt console-quick` loads the console without the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In more recent sbt versions (0.12 and newer), the following should suffice:

```
fork in run := true
```