# Is there any way to test a scala compiler plugin?

Tags: scala, plugins, compiler-construction

I am trying to setup tests for a scala compiler-plugin I am developping.

According to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713031/how-to-use-scalatest-to-develop-a-compiler-plugin-in-scala), it is possible to invoke the plugin programmatically. However, when I tried to do this the program could not find my plugin.

```
Error:(34, 25) not found: type GetFileFromAnnotation
      for (phase <- new GetFileFromAnnotation(this).components)
```

Both files are in the same package.

Here is the code which is trying to test the plugin (pulled from the question above), the commented out code is an alternative to the code above it and throws the same error:

```
package compilerPlugin

import scala.reflect.internal.util.BatchSourceFile
import scala.tools.nsc.io.VirtualDirectory
import scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter
import scala.tools.nsc.{Global, Settings}

object AnnotationFinderTest extends App {
  // prepare the code you want to compile
  val code =
"""
  |class Typestate(filename:String) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
  |
  |@Typestate(filename = "MyProtocol.txt")
  |class Cat{
  |  def comeAlive(): Unit = println("The cat is alive")
  |}
  |
  |object Main extends App {
  |  val cat = new Cat()
  |  cat.comeAlive()
  |}""".stripMargin

  val sources = List(new BatchSourceFile("<test>", code))
  println("sources "+sources)
  val settings = new Settings
  settings.usejavacp.value = true

  settings.outputDirs.setSingleOutput(new VirtualDirectory("(memory)", None))

  val compiler = new Global(settings, new ConsoleReporter(settings)) {
    override protected def computeInternalPhases () {
      super.computeInternalPhases
      for (phase <- new GetFileFromAnnotation(this).components)
        phasesSet += phase
    }
  }

    new compiler.Run() compileSources (sources)

}
```

The code for the GetFileFromAnnotation plugin is:

```
package compilerPlugin

import java.io.{FileNotFoundException, IOException}

import scala.tools.nsc
import nsc.Global
import nsc.Phase
import nsc.plugins.Plugin
import nsc.plugins.PluginComponent
import scala.io.BufferedSource
import scala.io.Source._

class GetFileFromAnnotation(val global: Global) extends Plugin {
  import global._

  val name = "GetFileFromAnnotation"
  val description = "gets file from typestate annotation"
  val components: List[PluginComponent] = List[PluginComponent](Component)

  private object Component extends PluginComponent {
    val global: GetFileFromAnnotation.this.global.type = GetFileFromAnnotation.this.global
    val runsAfter: List[String] = List[String]("parser")
    val phaseName: String = GetFileFromAnnotation.this.name
    def newPhase(_prev: Phase) = new GetFileFromAnnotationPhase(_prev)

    class GetFileFromAnnotationPhase(prev: Phase) extends StdPhase(prev) {
      override def name: String = GetFileFromAnnotation.this.name

      def printFile(filename: String): Unit ={
        val source = fromFile(filename)
        try {
          val it = source.getLines()
          while (it.hasNext)
            println(it.next())
        }
        catch{
          case e: IOException => println(s"Had an IOException trying to use file $filename")
        } finally {
          source.close
        }
      }

      def getFilenameFromAnnotation(annotation: Apply): Option[String] ={
        annotation match{
          case Apply(Select(New(Ident(TypeName("Typestate"))), con),List(NamedArg(Ident(TermName("filename")), Literal(Constant(filename))))) => Some(filename.toString)
          case Apply(Select(New(Ident(TypeName("Typestate"))), con),List(Literal(Constant(filename)))) => Some(filename.toString)
          case _ => None
        }
      }

      def apply(unit: CompilationUnit): Unit = {
        for (tree@q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" <- unit.body) {
          val annotations = mods.annotations
          for(annotation@Apply(arg1,arg2) <- annotations){
            getFilenameFromAnnotation(annotation) match{
              case Some(filename) => printFile(filename)
              case None => println("Not a Typestate annotation")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it even feasible to use this method to test a plugin or is the only way to do it to use mocking? Is there another way of doing this entirely?

UPDATE:
Thanks for the comment and the github example.
It ended up working fine with the edited test code above and prints out the protocol file as expected. I am not sure why it wasn't working before.

Comment: Can't reproduce. https://github.com/DmytroMitin/compiler-plugin-demo1 If I run `AnnotationFinderTest` in IDE it behaves as expected: it prints `sources List(<test>) aaa bbb` (`aaa bbb` are the lines in `MyProtocol.txt`). If I try to run `AnnotationFinderTest` in sbt shell I have errors `error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'class scala.native in compiler mirror''`, `scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation in compiler mirror not found`...

Comment: ... but the fix with `getClass.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader]` from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937135/5249621) doesn't work for me: `java.lang.ClassCastException: sbt.internal.LayeredClassLoader cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader`.